# Azure DevOps dacpac release on SQL database with Always Encrypted

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, dacpac, database-deployment

I have an SQL database in Azure with always encryption enabled (master key in Azure key vault) to encrypt the data in a particular table. Azure DB is on version Azure SQL Database v12.

Somehow, I am not able to deploy my dacpac DB project into it using Azure DevOps release pipeline. I am using 'Azure SQL Database deployment' task version 1.*

During the execution of the release pipeline, I am getting an error message “The element MPCMK1 is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.” MPCMK1 is the column master key already created in the target server (stored in key azure vault). Other than the deployment, the functionalities such as encryption/decryption and all working fine. I am not understanding why it says not supported in this version.

I added publish profile and configured to skip deploying column master keys, column encryption keys etc but still I am getting this message on the key that is in the target server.

I removed the key from the target server just for testing, and this error went away. But that doesn't help me as removing the key will require to remove encryptions from the tables and all. But this was just to make sure the error is on the target but not on the source.

Also tried the arguments /p:AllowIncompatiblePlatform=True  /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=false but no luck.

It would be great if someone can help me on this.

Comment: It seems that you are using CMK key, do you mind exporting the release definition, then share the definition and details log here? I want to check the task Azure SQL Database deployment setting(You could also select the tab Deployment Package and then share the screenshot here). Thanks

Comment: Hi Vito, Thanks for your response. I have uploaded the log and yaml view of the task here . Redacted sensitive information . Please let me know if this is helpful. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xjgS4RhkqxHm8IT8I6jFCtUEyNvwKfap?usp=sharing